# Examples of well-displayed mathematics on the internet

Tags: soft-question, online-resources

An off-topic question asked at [Mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/3036/) by Andrew Stacey; but one which fits here:

I'm interested in hearing of examples of mathematical (or, at a pinch, scientific) websites with serious content where the design of the website actually makes it easy to read and absorb the material. To be absolutely clear, the mathematical content of the website should be on the website itself and not in an electronic article (so meta-sites that make it easy to find material, like MathSciNet or the arXiv, don't count).

Edit: I'm extending this to non-internet material. I want examples where the design of the document/website/whatever actually helped when reading the material.

As a little background, I know that LaTeX is meant to help us separate content from context and concentrate on each one in turn, but I often feel when reading an article that the author has concentrated solely on the content and left all of the context to TeX. This is most obvious with websites where there are some really well-designed websites to compare with, but holds as well with articles.

Answer (score 1):

For students in lower level university courses, there are two amazing resources.

1. [Paul's online math notes](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/). My linear algebra book was complete garbage. I pretty much used these notes to get through the class. It explains everything very well and does not assume that you already know graduate level mathematics. Presentation wise, its very simple. A plain HTML website, however content is king.
2. And ofcourse, Khan Academy. I think everyone knows about Khan.
3. Last but not least, I would like to add the MIT online courses. I didn't like them that much but they did help me. Maybe its just me but I can not learn anything while staring at a computer screen.

Comment: Isn't Khan's academy a set of videos? How is it an example of good typesetting/layout? And the MIT online courses mostly don't have any special typesetting either.

Comment: Even your first point says "A plain HTML website, however content is king." So this is not an answer to this question at all!

Comment: His question isnt about type-setting/layout. He just extended the question to include that part. His first sentence states that he is interested in hearing examples of mathematical websites with serious content where the design helps the content. For pauls notes, I mentioned that the website is rather bland but there is good content. I just mentioned the other two because of there good mathematical content, not so much the design/layout of the website.

Comment: Actually, the question is specifically about design ("well-displayed", "where the design of the website actually makes it easy", etc.) (Also a question just about mathematics on the internet seems way too broad IMHO.) The original question on Math Overflow makes the emphases more clear, but the formatting seems to be have been lost in the copying.

Comment: This argument is useless. He is asking about mathematical content but in an environment where its easy to read. I gave him 3 good resources for mathematical content where I think its easy to read and absorb the material. He also stated that he wanted content on the site itself and not articles. 

Why would a question about website design be on a Math related discussion?

Answer (score 1):

Paul Bourke's [website](http://local.wasp.uwa.edu.au/~pbourke/), in particular his [geometry](http://local.wasp.uwa.edu.au/~pbourke/geometry/) section fueled my passion for geometry at a young age, infact I learned the idea of analytic geometry from it. For this reason it holds a special place in my heart. It is a very rich site full of graphics and derivations, very easy to get sucked in and lose a few hours!